# Why are Unity calls chained?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm learning about the Unity dependency injection container, and I always see lots of code like this:

```
using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
{
    container
        .RegisterType<IView, Form>()
        .RegisterType<IService, Service>(
            new InjectionProperty("Logger")
         )
        .RegisterType<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>()
        .RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>("UI")
        .RegisterInstance(new TraceSource("UI", SourceLevels.All))
        .RegisterType<Presenter>(
            new InjectionProperty("Logger", 
                new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>("UI")
            )
         );

        Presenter presenter = container.Resolve<Presenter>();

        //do stuff with presenter
}
```

My question is why are the calls chained? I.E. why could the above not be written as follows:

```
using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
{
    container.RegisterType<IView, Form>();
    container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(
            new InjectionProperty("Logger")
         );
    container.RegisterType<ILogger, ConsoleLogger>();
    container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>("UI");
    container.RegisterInstance(new TraceSource("UI", SourceLevels.All));
    container.RegisterType<Presenter>(
        new InjectionProperty("Logger", 
                new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>("UI")
        )
    );

    Presenter presenter = container.Resolve<Presenter>();

    //do stuff with presenter
}
```

Or is this purely a style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Purely style. It's the "fluent" style.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: +1. It reduces noise - "container" in the second example is redundant information.

Comment: Ah. So it's pretty similar to how jQuery operates in that sense.